# PHP Return function prints text on top of page

Tags: php, html

When i replace the '.$content().' with a string like "Test" it prints "Test" in the middle of the page in the correct place. but when i use the variable '.$content().' it prints "Test" on the top-left of the page. (see return in class pages).

i have used this "return method" lots of times and this is the first time it won't work.

I want to use the $content variable how it is in the script but i want the output in the correct place.

Timo

Core.php

```
class site {
function __construct($title,$content) {
    echo '  <html>
            <head>
            <title>'.$title.'</title>           
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
            <link href="core/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body>  
            <header id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>DataBaas</h1>
                    <h2>Baas over je data</h2>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="article">
                    '.$content().'
                <div>
            </div>
            </body>     
            </html>';
    }
}
class pages {
    function home() {
    return 'Test';
    }
}
```

Index.php is like:

```
<?php
include_once("core/core.php");
$pages = new pages;
$thispage = $pages->home();
$site = new site('Home',function(){global $thispage; echo $thispage;});
?>
```

Comment: This is really really wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
<?php
include_once("core/core.php");
$pages = new pages;
$thispage = $pages->home();
$site = new site('Home',function(){global $thispage; return $thispage;});
?>
```

Not the methodology I would personally follow... but ey...

Comment: Yeah this was learned to me by someone that was better than me so i thougt it was a good way....  @cstruter

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat though ;) Always do your own research, make up your own mind, weigh the pros and cons of an approach - not always viable to rely on "Authorities"

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is a wrong way of coding an website, I would suggest you make some changes like:

```
interface Renderable
{
    public function render();
}

interface Page
{
    public function getTitle();
    public function getContent();
}

class Site implements Renderable
{
   private $page;

   public function addPage(Page $page)
   {
       $this->page = $page;
   }

   public function render()
   {
      echo '
         <html>
            <head>
            <title>'.$this->page->getTitle().'</title>           
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
            <link href="core/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <body>  
            <header id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>DataBaas</h1>
                    <h2>Baas over je data</h2>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="article">
                    ' . $this->page->getContent() . '
                <div>
            </div>
            </body>     
            </html>';
   }
}

class Home implements Page
{
   public function getTitle()
   {
      return 'Home';
   }

   public function getContent()
   {
      return 'Test';
   }
}
```

In your index you should have something like:

```
$site = new Site()
$site->addPage(new Home);
$site->render();
```

Now you already learned something about interfaces and how the classes implementing them can be typehinted in the methods.